# React won't render multiple fetched API's to the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

Link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-brook-flxdf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

I can successfully display Tavares' fetched data to the DOM through a .map statement. However, once I try to load up the second and third players data using the exact same way (they're there, just commented out right now) - under Tavares' .map - I get thrown an error of, "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined", and the first .map (Matthews) after Tavares'.

Trying to figure out why this error is displaying, and why I can't map all three data points to the DOM.

App.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  // Set initial state for data
  const [data, setData] = useState({ tavares: [], matthews: [], marner: [] });

  // Fetch data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      // Grab all players API's
      let tavares =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8475166?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let matthews =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8479318?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      let marner =
        "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8478483?expand=person.stats&stats=yearByYear,careerRegularSeason&expand=stats.team&site=en_nhlCA";
      // Axios to get all api's
      axios
        .all([axios.get(tavares), axios.get(matthews), axios.get(marner)])
        .then(
          axios.spread((tavares, matthews, marner) => {
            setData(
              { tavares: [tavares.data.people[0]] },
              { matthews: [matthews.data.people[0]] },
              { marner: [marner.data.people[0]] }
            );
            console.log("Tavares:", tavares.data.people[0]);
            console.log("Matthews:", matthews.data.people[0]);
            console.log("Marner:", marner.data.people[0]);
          })
        );
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Tavares</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.tavares.map(item => (
          <li key={item.objectID}>
            <p>{item.id}</p>
            <p>{item.primaryNumber}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {/* <h1>Matthews</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.matthews.map(item => (
          <li key={item.objectID}>
            <p>{item.id}</p>
            <p>{item.primaryNumber}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <h1>Marner</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.marner.map(item => (
          <li key={item.objectID}>
            <p>{item.id}</p>
            <p>{item.primaryNumber}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul> */}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setData` with three arguments (three objects with one player each) rather than an object with all players. This means only the first object with only `tavares` is getting set as your `data` (try logging your `data` object before rendering to see).

You are doing:

```
        setData(
          { tavares: [tavares.data.people[0]] },
          { matthews: [matthews.data.people[0]] },
          { marner: [marner.data.people[0]] }
        );
```

When you should be doing:

```
        setData({
          tavares: [tavares.data.people[0],
          matthews: [matthews.data.people[0]],
          marner: [marner.data.people[0]]
        });
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!